# YouTube API: 'Official Content Only?'

Tags: youtube-api

When using the YouTube api to query and retrieve videos, is there a way to limit results only official content? I want to retrieve the new music videos for certain artists but I want to make sure I am only receiving real videos and not UGC stuff. Can this be accomplished? Thank you.

Comment: You could limit your query to the youtube pages of the record companies.

Comment: Please let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74893025) on a very similar StackOverflow question solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no search parameter that ensures that you only get back "real" music videos. (And the line between a "real" video and user-generated content isn't always clear.)