# How to detect official artist channel using youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to detect is it official artist channel or not, using youtube api? Official channel has special label next to title, like this one https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBQZwaNPFfJ1gZ1fLZpAEGw, but it doesn't appear in title from api.

Comment: I want to know too. My guess it could be `topicId` of channel

Comment: No, nothing special in topicId, just music genre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.

I recommend you to try out my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/bed0a4144bae526d73cbc80ae79e3fbd3b4b6077#diff-651cb6f72df27343556303c689f24c67c4cb90e2881f464e665c151429551dacR305-R317) [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com). Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/channels?part=approval&id=CHANNEL_ID, you will get whether or not the given channel is an official artist in `item["approval"]` by checking if this value is `Official Artist Channel`.

For instance [the YouTube channel `UC0aMaqIs997ggjDs_Q9UYiw`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0aMaqIs997ggjDs_Q9UYiw) is an official artist channel, with this channel id you would get:

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "UC0aMaqIs997ggjDs_Q9UYiw",
            "approval": "Official Artist Channel"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up scraping the channel page. Split the text around ',"headerlinks"'. You'll have two items. Look at the very end of the first item (e.g. text.split(',"headerlinks"')[0][-30:] and test if "verified" or "official artist channel" is there.

Slow but works for me as this is not something that has to be done frequently.