# YouTube Data API finding Official Artist Channels

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm working on an app and I am trying to find the best way to get music videos (videoCategoryId 10) but only from Official Artist Channel.
I've been doing research on the best way to do this, but haven't been successful.

If anyone has a workaround or know how to determine official Artist Channels, can you please share?

Comment: Any luck? I too am looking for a way to determine if a channel is an Official Artist Channel from the api response

Comment: no, but I have found a site that has the youtube ID linked to the artist. If you want to work together to get this info, I am willing to collaborate on something.

Comment: [@GarrettSimpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380990/garrett-simpson) and [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11986421/paul-anthony) please let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74893025) on a very similar StackOverflow question solves your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect official artist channel using youtube api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55928904/how-to-detect-official-artist-channel-using-youtube-api)

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead and test this tonight when i get home.